# Insert values in new column in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have a table `T` with some data having 3 rows. Now I added a new column `c`.
Now I want to insert values into `c` for existing rows.
I do it like this :

```
insert into T (c) values(1),(2),(3);
```

But instead of updating existing data, it inserted new rows.
How can I update existing data ?
I don't want to specify where clause. I just want to add values serial wise as insert does.

Comment: Using `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`... Plenty of questions like this one on SO

Comment: @njk: How would that work if the primary key is not being included in the insert?

Comment: @mellamokb Jumped the wagon there.

Answer (score 2):

You would use the UPDATE statement to assign values to columns of existing rows.

```
UPDATE t
   SET t.c = 1
 WHERE t.a = 1 ;
```

---

To assign unique, sequential integer to each existing row, you'd need to make use of the primary key, or a unique identifier from each row.  In this example, we assume that the `id` column is unique:

```
UPDATE t
  JOIN ( SELECT r.id
              , @i := @i + 1 AS i
           FROM t r
           JOIN (SELECT @i := 0) n
          ORDER BY r.id
        ) s
    ON s.id = t.id 
   SET t.c = s.i
```

Actually, you can also do this:

```
UPDATE t
  JOIN ( SELECT @i := 0 ) n
   SET t.c = @i := @i + 1
 ORDER BY t.id
```

It sounds like you might want to investigate the AUTO_INCREMENT attribute.

Comment: But how can update them without specifying where clause, I mean just add serial wise.

Comment: UPDATE t
   SET t.c = 1 WHERE t.c IS NULL;

Comment: @almog.ori but then all t.c entries would be 1

Comment: this is a default value for the new column,

Comment: @spencer7593 no I don't want to use AUTO_INCREMENT, incremental values of c was just an example. C.values can be anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query

```
UPDATE Table
SET Col1='1', Col2='2'
```

and so on...

Also, you can use where condition, if you want to update data with some specified conditions, as below:
---it's just an example of query used in my database---

```
UPDATE City_Employee
SET City='Banglore' where (City='Delhi')
```

Best of luck !